# Accessing local files on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm using Apache Tomcat 7 and I have a servlet where it lists all files in a directory and allows users to download the files by clicking on a link.

Here is the problem:

The files that I am accessing in the servlet are NOT in project directory itself. They are in a directory outside of the tomcat directory itself

I.E.

Project is in /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.53
Files are in /files/

When I use an anchor tag, I can't reference using href="" because that assumes the directory is within the WebContent folder of the project.

I tried doing `href="file:///files/<FILE NAME>` but I could not click on the link to download the file so something must be wrong.

Anyone know how to work around this?

EDIT: I should also point out this isn't running on my local machine. This is on a server.

Comment: `file://` in a web-application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably better off looking at [Tomcat Aliases](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Standard_Implementation). They let you mount external directories in to your web app's context, and have Tomcat serve the file directly.

Addenda:

The part of a URL before the `:` is called the "scheme". Examples include "http", "https", "ftp", as well as "file".

The scheme tells the browser "what to do" with the rest of the URL, different schemes can have different formats after the `:`.

So, a URL starting with `file://` use the "file" scheme. The file scheme tells the browser to try and open the filename specified by the rest of the URL. That filename is a LOCAL filename. Local to the browser. Not the server.

You would almost never use the `file://` type of URL on a server based application, but only on a client side application.

Comment: You're right, but @SlashTag first needs to understand *why* ```file://``` isn't working.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann I do understand why `file://` isn't working thanks to this answer.

Comment: This was an excellent answer. It answered exactly what I wanted, in the simplest fashion. Additionally, the extra info was useful knowledge. Marked as best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat by itself can only serve files in the WebContent directory and not in WEB-INF. But the servlet can access any file on server.
So you have basically 2 solutions:

- either linking the external dir under WebContent if is causes no security problem and if Tomcat accept to follow symlinks (assuming server under Unix like system such as Linux)
- either explicitely do the conversion in the WebApplication by constructing a pseudo directory listing and serving files

In that second solution, you choose an arbitrary root url in the servlet domain such as `http:server.domain.org/app/path/to/files`. The files directory has not to exist under WebContent, but your must have a controller that responds to urls like `http:server.domain.org/app/path/to/files/myfile.ext` and serves directly the file of same name under the external directory.

This second solution is much more complicated but offers a greatest level of control on what is really accessible through the application. IMHO you should only use it if you have security needs for it or have to to special operations. I've used it to have full control for an application needing to upload and download files relatively to a business URL.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **javax.servlet.Filter** interface.

```
public class ResourceProxyFilter implements Filter {

    private static final String PROXY_CONTROLLER_PREFIX = "/proxyFilter/";

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException {
        String requestURI = getRequestURI(request);

        File requestedResource = getRequestedResource(requestURI);
        sendResponse(response, requestedResource);
    }

    private String getRequestURI(ServletRequest request) {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        return httpRequest.getRequestURI();
    }

    private File getRequestedResource(String requestURI) {
        String requestedResourcePath = requestURI.substring(requestURI.indexOf(PROXY_CONTROLLER_PREFIX) + PROXY_CONTROLLER_PREFIX.length());
        File dirWithYourFiles = new File("/files");

        return new File(dirWithYourFiles, requestedResourcePath);
    }

    private void sendResponse(ServletResponse response, File requestedResource) throws IOException {
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        ServletOutputStream writer = httpResponse.getOutputStream();
        writer.write(ByteStreams.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(requestedResource)));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Then you have to add your filter to web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>resourceProxyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>eu.company.ResourceProxyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>resourceProxyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/proxyFilter/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```